# ¿Cómo poner en negrita el texto de una subcadena XML de los resources de Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

¡Buenas!, he estado buscando como poner letra bold en una substrig de la carpeta resources y sólo he encontrado la solución de los tags html, el problema es que ya lo he hecho y no parece haber algún cambio.

Tengo un text view cuyo texto quiero que se cargue desde los recursos:

```
<string name="cuerpo_info">
<b>Progamado por:</b> Nombre Programador\n
    <b>Fecha de creación:</b> 20 abril del 2019.\n
    <b>Licencia:</b> Whatever.

</string>
```

Como pueden observar, en la vista diseño no veo ningún cambio reflejado:

[image: iles]

¿Alguna idea?, os doy las gracias por adelantado por vuestro tiempo, ¡saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Primero deberás cargar en una variable el TextView. Supongamos que el id de tu TextView es `mitextview`

Pues tendrías que hacer:

```
TextView mitextview = findViewById(R.id.mitextview);
```

Ahora ya tienes el textview almacenado en una variable de tu controlador. Ahora para darle el estilo bold, harías lo siguiente:

```
mitextiew.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

o bien

```
mitextview.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Si quieres que esto se haga al pulsar un botón, pues lo pondrás en el listener del botón. Si quieres que se haga al iniciar la activity, ponlo dentro del método `onCreate()`

---

También puedes hacerlo vía xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/elnombredeturecurso"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
/>
```

Comment: ¡Buenas!, gracias por responder, pero eso sólo funciona para cambiar todo el texto. ¿Necesito hacer un textview por cada palabra?

Comment: Yo creo que si, que sería lo más sencillo si la cadena es invariable, es decir, que va a ser así siempre.